# Display elements of requested fact

Tags: prolog

I am very new to Prolog and I'm struggling to understand what I have done wrong. I'm trying to get user input in the form of one keyword and then display the full details of whichever class it is.
My code will display the information if I query in this format `course(managing, A, B, C, D, E)` but won't work when I try to have it simplified.

Could someone please tell me how I should edit my code so that it will ask what course I would like information on and only require a one word answer before displaying all information related to that course?

```
course(
    accouting,
    acc10707,
    day(tuesday),
    time(1100, 1250),
    prof(ayesha, mujib),
    b228
).
course(
    managing,
    mng10247,
    day(thursday),
    time(1000, 1150),
    prof(brian, morris),
    b228
).
course(
    communication,
    com00207,
    day(monday),
    time(1000, 1250),
    prof(ali, bec),
    b727
).

details :-
    write('Please enter unit keyword.'),
    nl,
    read(Name),
    course(Name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room), 
    write(Name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code you gave I get the following errors with [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog) version 1.4.4:

```
| ?- details.
Please enter unit keyword.
communication.
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,write/6),details/0)
```

What's the problem?

- The last goal in `details/0` is `write(Name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room)`.
- You inadvertently tried using `write/6`, which does not exist.

Solution(s)?

1. **Use the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel)** instead of performing side-effects in `details/0`!

   Let's define `details_of/2`. Its first argument is a structure `c/6`.

   ```
   details_of(Details,Course_name) :-
       Details = c(Course_name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room),
       course(Course_name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room).
   ```

   Sample use:

   ```
   | ?- details_of(X,communication).

   X = c(communication,com00207,day(monday),time(1000,1250),prof(ali,bec),b727)

   yes
   ```
2. *Quick fix:* Instead of `write/6` use `write/1` and a structure `c/6`.

   Replace `write(Name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room)` by
   `write(c(Name,Code,Day,Time,Prof,Room))`.

   ```
   | ?- details.
   Please enter unit keyword.
   communication.
   c(communication,com00207,day(monday),time(1000,1250),prof(ali,bec),b727)

   yes
   ```